# ANTLR grammar for defining/calling multi-parameter functions

Tags: function, parameters, antlr, antlr3

I have a grammar that I'd like to include multi-parameter functions in (like `f(x,y)`). I'm using AST output with my own tree parser. Right now my parameter list production is

```
paramdefs: (ID COMMA)* ID ;
```

This works fine, but the AST output for

```
z(x,y)=expression
```

is

```
(FUNC (z)(x)(,)(y)(expression))
```

(i.e. it's very flat).

The `FUNC` CommonTree's children, in the general case, are {`function name`, `parameter`, `comma`, `parameter`, `defined expression`}, for any number of parameters. I'd like the parameter list to be a single child and not have commas (this would make it easier to walk the tree).

Ideally, this is what the tree would look like:

```
(FUNC (z)((x)(y))(expression))
```

(note the absence of the comma element and the grouping of `x` and `y`.

Relevant associated areas of the grammar:

```
funcdef: ID  '(' paramdefs ')' '=' expr -> ^(FUNC ID paramdefs expr) ;

paramdefs: (ID COMMA)* ID ;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create a tree like this:

[image]

for the input `z(x,y)=expr`, do the following:

```
grammar ...

...

tokens {
  FUNC;
  PARAMS;
}

...

funcdef
  :  ID  '(' paramdefs ')' '=' expr   -> ^(FUNC ID paramdefs expr) 
  ;

paramdefs
  :  (ID COMMA)* ID                   -> ^(PARAMS ID+)
  ;
```